# Why isn't my conditional formatting working in Google Sheets? Simple COUNTIFS

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to format all cells in column D when:

- R=closed
- D=blank
- **EDIT: E IS NOT "NOT ON CR"**

---

Here is my custom formula in Google Sheets. Doesn't work. ALL cells in column D get highlighted

`=COUNTIFS(R:R, "Closed", D:D, "")`

Changed formula to: **`=COUNTIFS(R:R, "Closed", D:D, "", E:E, "<>NOT ON CR")`**

---

I also tried this but it doesn't work. NO cells in column D get highlighted

`=COUNTIFS(R:R, "Closed", D:D, "<0")`

Changed formula to: **`=COUNTIFS(R:R, "Closed", D:D, "<0", E:E, "<>NOT ON CR")`**

Comment: The first way seems to work for me. COUNTIFS increments if both values are true. My R column has 3 rows of "Closed", and of those, two are blank. COUNTIFS returns 2

Comment: @dementis, yes, i want it to only conditionally format when both these cases are true (ie D1=highlighted when R1=closed AND when D1=blank). If R1=closed, but D1 is filled, then I don't want D1 to be highlighted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=COUNTIFS( $D1, "",$R1, "Closed")
```

Apply to D1:D

Comment: MAGIC! I even added my new condition `$E1, "<>NOT ON CR"` and works like a charm! thank you, @Ed Nelson!